# rxjs how to handle error in subscriber's next

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I'm using rxjs in a library to expose an `Observable` that clients can subscribe to to consume messages. I want to be able to react appropriately if the subscriber's `next` function throws an error. However, I'm not seeing any obvious way to detect that. For example:

```
const observable = new Observable<string>((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next('first')
  subscriber.next('second')
  subscriber.complete()
})

observable.subscribe(() => {
  throw new Error('oh no!')
})
```

I have tried all of the following, but the errors are bubbled all the way up to a global scope that's surfaced either in an `onUnhandledError` function provided to the global config, or in absence of that, the node process's `unhandledException` event.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
  console.error('IN UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION HANDLER', error.message)
})

export function main() {
  try {
    const observable = new Observable<string>((subscriber) => {
      try {
        subscriber.next('first')
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('IN OBSERVABLE CATCH', error.message)
      }
      subscriber.complete()
    }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('CATCHERROR PIPE', error.message)
        return of('there was an error!!!!')
      }),
    )

    observable.subscribe({
      next: (_value) => {
        throw new Error('oh no!')
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('IN OBSERVER ERROR HANDLER', error.message)
      },
      complete: () => console.log('complete!'),
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('IN MAIN CATCH', error.message)
  }
}
```

This logs:

```
complete!
IN UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION HANDLER oh no!
```

The docs don't make a big fuss about ensuring that subscribers avoid throwing errors at all costs, but I don't see a standard mechanism for handling it short of some sort of "observer wrapper" (that gets a bit ugly with the overloads).

Comment: I am pretty sure that what you are trying is not possible. And even if it was, I don't see any useful scenario, where it would make sense. Usually the control flow of observables it pretty clear: information will flow from the source to subscribers via pipes. Handling errors from subsriptions in the pipe (or source observable) would be the opposite, because information will flow back from subspriptions "upstream".

Comment: There are plenty of useful scenarios. There are lots of data sources that require acknowledgement when a message is handled successfully. Queues, for example, need acknowldgement. A good library would absolve clients of the requirement to manage this and simply allow them to deal with the contained data in a source-agnostic way. As it stands, that's not possible. Each client must reimplement the acknowledgement behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that there is effectively no way to handle errors from observers.

When using `Observable.subscribe`, it wraps your observer functions in a "SafeSubscriber". This then wraps the supplied functions with a [ConsumerObserver](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/afac3d574323333572987e043adcd0f8d4cff546/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L154). This wraps each in a `try/catch` that, [upon errors](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/afac3d574323333572987e043adcd0f8d4cff546/src/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.ts#L13), either:

- sends them to an optional `onUnhandledError` function you can supply to the rxjs config
- sends them "into the ether" to be picked up by the node process

There is no context, and no way to hook into it. Effectively, errors from `next`, `error`, or `complete` handlers just silently disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Glad I learned something new :)